# fgrep: Sorting the results to files

Tags: shell, grep, pipe

I am just about to learn some shell scripting and I am really struggling with getting what I want with the results of frgep. Is there way to pipe the results of fgrep to files in way that each pattern is saved into files that only contain the lines belonging to these patterns.

My Input file looks like:

```
@ABC;123;bc=Pattern_1;
@DEF;456;bc=Pattern_1;
@ZYR;678;bc=Pattern_2;
@OPZ;888;bc=Pattern_2;
```

My file I am using for pattern search looks like:

```
Pattern.txt:
Pattern_1
Pattern_2
Pattern_3
```

Now I do a fgrep (I also need the following 3 lines of each entry):

```
fgrep -A 3 -f Pattern.txt huge_file
```

That works perfectly. But I want to have the results sorted in to files. Meaning every line which contains Pattern_1 should be in a result file e.g. Pattern_1.txt. The other patterns in the same way (pattern_2 lines should end up in pattern_2.txt and so on).

```
Pattern_1.txt:
ABC Pattern_1 123
DEF Pattern_1 456
...

Pattern_2.txt:
ZYR Pattern_2 678
OPZ Pattern_2 888
...
```

In principle I could a for loop for every pattern and do a fgrep every time and save the results to the files. But is there is more elegant way to pipe the results of the fgrep on the fly in many files depending on the pattern. It is of relevance since the file containing the pattern is huge and it takes while to run fgrep once.
Is this possible? I played arround with if clauses after piping but I am not able get the right syntax to to do what I want to do. Is this possible?

Thanks.
Carsten

Comment: Can you provide an example of the file you are searching in ?

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated the question. The input format is not tabulated but separated by tabs and at the begin of each line there is an @.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres an awk one liner that i think does what you require.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]}{for(i in a){if(i==$2)print $0 >> $2}}' Pattern.txt hugefile
```

This should work for updated specs, didnt have time to make it look nice.

```
awk -F";" 'NR==FNR{a[$0]}{for(i in a){if(i==substr($3,4))print substr($1,2),substr($3,4),$2 >> substr($3,4)}}' Pattern.txt hugefile
```

And slightly reduced

```
awk -F";" 'NR==FNR{a[$0]}{x=substr($3,4);for(i in a){if(i==x)print substr($1,2),x,$2 >> x}}' Pattern.txt hugefile
```

Comment: Thank you! That is very very close to what I am looking for. Since I don't have a tabulated input file (see edited and updated question) the if clause is a problem (I think... - but may be I am wrong).

Comment: are the lines in the input file always the same length ?

Comment: Thanks! That does exactly what I want.